# How to insert a new line into a Sharepoint multiple line field?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, web-services

I am inserting items into a Sharepoint list using C# and accessing the lists.asmx web service.  One of the fields in the list is a multiple line text field (rich text), and I want to insert line breaks into the field.  What characters do I put in the XML request to insert a line break?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same setup as you and I tired `<br />` but it won't translate over if you are using an XML element to update the list.

When your generating your text, use **`<![CDATA[<br/>]]>`** instead of **`<br />`** .

This will translate over, tested and verified.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Environment.NewLine
```

I had the exact same problem, but neither `<br />` nor `<br/>` worked for me within `<![CDATA[` In the end I removed CDATA and treated the text as a regular string, inserting the `System.Environment.NewLine` property where ever a line break was needed.

Comment: OK, I found the difference, when the Multi-line Text Field's html property is "true" (ie Rich Text or Enhanced Rich Text) then use CDATA with `<br/>` But if you are adding Plain Text, treat it as a plain string using `System.Environment.NewLine` for your line breaks.

Comment: More precisely: In my prior comment I said "html property" It's actually the "SPFieldMultiLineText" field's "RichTextMode" property.  When set to `SPRichTextMode.FullHtml` use CDATA with `<br/>`.  But when set to `SPRichTextMode.Compatible` (which is plain text) use `System.Environment.NewLine` to create a line break.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `<br />` tags to the text. the content of the field is stored in a CDATA element.